# Close votes review audits

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

When reviewing, sometimes I got this result:

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.
>   The post has already been removed, but if it hadn't your response
>   would have helped to ensure that it was. Thanks!

I got this message when I review First Posts, Reopen Posts, Suggested Edits and Low Quality Posts.

But for Close Votes review, I've doing almost 600 Close Votes and I never got that message. Is review testing is applied to Close Votes?

If no review testing for Close Votes, what is the reason?

Comment: But I never got that test until 600 votes..

Comment: Not all audits give you a 'congratulations' message.

Comment: So how can I know that I've being tested? What happen if I always choose 'Leave Open' in close votes review?

Comment: If you *fail* the audit you are always told and educated.

Comment: Interestingly failing an audit still seems to count towards your badge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny thing... When you asked this question, Close Review audits weren't implemented yet (although [someone obviously thought they were](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/157172/9)).

Now they are. You'll encounter both known-good and known-bad posts while reviewing questions in both the Close and Reopen queues. Vote to reopen a bad one (or vote to close a good one) and you'll see a message like:

[image: The YOU DUN FAILED, BOY message]

There's a somewhat more congratulatory message if you succeed, so the only way to not know you've been audited is to skip the audit.

Comment: Can this be extended? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177642/acceptable-honeypot-suggested-edits

Comment: Probably; edits are a bit tricky though, it'll take some work.

Comment: I managed the reverse trick - I decided to only do 5 reviews yesterday, then this morning when I restarted my browser that review turned out to have been an audit (someone else got it and passed).

Comment: I have over 1500 reviews in the Close votes section... and I have never passed/failed an audit there. Ever. So do they actually exist ? Your answer seems not to be on the same page with reality...

Comment: You're right, @Radu - you haven't. Auditing is semi-random; you've apparently been *very, very lucky*.