# Are there actually review audits for the close vote queue?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

> *Similar to [Close votes review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174128/178687)*
>
> ***Not a duplicate** of [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)*

I've run into audits on every queue except the close vote queue, on which I've done nearly 300 reviews since the audits were (supposed) to have been put in place.

[What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) claims that close vote audits "present a reviewer with a question which the system has determined should be open or closed based on various criteria." I have seen such audits only in the reopen queue.

Over at the very similar question [Close votes review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174128/178687), it was asserted that "not all audits give you a 'congratulations' message". This doesn't agree with the answer at [Add a positive feedback for all types of review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170528/178687), which says that "congratulations" messages have been added to *every* audit regardless of queue.

I've never seen "congratulations" on the close vote review queue. Furthermore, I just checked the  40 close vote reviews I did today, and not a single one is shown as being a review audit.

What's going on? Are there really no review audits on close votes? If there are, am I somehow exempt from them? If there aren't, why is that? It seems that close votes are just as deserving of audits to avoid abuse (e.g. always blindly voting with the closing majority or always leaving open).

Comment: The larger problem with this review queue is it's extremely hard to select good candidates. There are tons and tons of very highly upvoted questions out there from the olden days that do *need* to be closed, so bombarding users with audits here would only cause frustration and start banning people from the queue who are just trying to close questions that *legitimately* need closed. We already have this problem with the Reopen Votes queue, which generates quite a few edge-case audits.

Comment: There weren't by the time this question was posted but they were [added later](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177695/152859).

Comment: If you still don't get any audits: [Are you using a filter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182761/skipping-close-vote-audits-successfully)

Answer (score 2):

Like [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174488/are-there-actually-review-audits-for-the-close-vote-queue/236662#comment557080_174488) and [Simon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174488/are-there-actually-review-audits-for-the-close-vote-queue/236662#comment653536_174488) mentioned in the comments, there was a time when if you used a filter while in the close vote review queue, than you wouldn't get any audits.

That has been fixed for some time now, thankfully. However, there still are some kinks, since if you filter by certain tags, and you see a question come up that doesn't include any of the tags you're filtering by, then you know it's an audit.

But you should really treat every review you do as important as an audit.