# Skipping close vote audits successfully

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, review-audits

I've been reading about close vote review audits for quite some time now. I used to think that these audits appear only for users who do not have either of [Steward](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/185/steward) or the [Reviewer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/169/reviewer) badges; which is why, I never had faced any reviews until a few days ago.

I think it is **either** a *bug* or an *easter-egg*; that the close vote audits can be skipped/removed completely from appearing.

I've tested around with it for quite some days now, and the trick is to just use any kind of filter; either by *tags* or by *close reasons*; in the review task list.

I haven't been able to test it with other review queues as those do not get as huge as 50k.

---

### Edit

I reset my filters again today (after nearly 2 weeks) and was provided an audit within a few minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2241112 (of course I passed :/ )

Comment: Could it be coincidence? Audits are chosen randomly, so if you somehow filter your list, it's unlikelier (wtf? That word exists? I just made it up...) that you encounter them.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unlikelier ;)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby erm, how often are the close vote audits presented to you? Also, edited with a link to most recent audit.

Comment: Did it match your filters, or would it have been hidden?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby This time, it would have been hidden.

Comment: I just got the Steward badge and I haven't seen any close vote audits either (filtering by close reason: Off-topic).

Comment: Wild guess as a programmer/bug creator: audits are missing the close reason or have it in the wrong place in database, so when you have filter it will never pick audits indeed.

Comment: (Although technically, this question was first, the "duplicate" was just answered and this has now been enabled so this can be marked with `status-completed`)