# Filtered Review Queue doesn't show any audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

In the last 3 days I have only been reviewing a filtered review queue. That's 120 reviews **without a single audit**.

Comment: Thats why I haven't been getting any audits! I can reproduce, I also haven't had any audits on the close review

Comment: @RichardTingle - I guess technically you'd have to have counted 120 reviews without getting audited, in order to "reproduce" this, since one can't prove a negative. But I'm in agreement with the _feeling_ that this might be true, because I had been using the off-topic filter for nearly a year, and I'd never been audited. In fact, probably for this reason, I didn't even know there were such things as "audits" until it was implemented for Suggested Edits.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182761/skipping-close-vote-audits-successfully

Comment: I've been noticing this for a while. I've been using filter on the review queue for weeks, not getting any audits. But when I turn off the filter, it doesn't take long until I get an audit. I searched meta and found that there were already questions about it (although old, but still) so I didn't ask again about it (but perhaps I should have)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174488/are-there-actually-review-audits-for-the-close-vote-queue?rq=1 (perhaps the OP there is actually using a filter on the queue)

Comment: @acheong87 According to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174128/close-votes-review-audits/177695#177695) audits for the close queue seems to have been implemented shortly before April 24th, 2013.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We've been caught... That's because until recently audits for queues where users had filters weren't even <strike>implemented</strike> enabled.

I guess I can just wish you good luck having *fun* with those, you asked for it ;)

Comment: Way to go! I just got [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296621/how-to-render-derived-types-of-a-class-differently) in my review queue but with the "java" tag added (since I don't have any other of those tags in my filter). I was on my way to retag the question to remove the java tag but then I discovered that there is none! I've got a feeling that these audits are going to be easy if it continues like this.

Comment: [Thanks](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3309641) but why do I get to review `perl, http, pipes` tags when clearly my filter is to only review `VBA, Excel-VBA`?

Comment: for technical reasons we aren't querying for audits with filters enabled, we just fake the audit post, so that it looks like it matches your filters... which completely serves the purpose of testing whether or not you're paying attention to what you click while reviewing

Comment: Ah! To save a meta question, @m0sa, that's why I'll get asked if a specific post is unclear (when my filter is for duplicates only)?