# Audits bug in the filtered review queue

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

Just recently the [audits have been introduced to filtered review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204269/filtered-review-queue-doesnt-show-any-audits).

I've got [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3309641) this morning which seems to be out of scope for my filtered list.

I have filtered my list to only review `VBA` and `Excel-VBA` tags while the audit is tagged with `perl` `http` `pipes` which have nothing in common with VBA.

I see a problem with the way the system currently works

- Since I have a filtered list of tags, once I see a differently tagged question I already know it's an audit. Come on, that's too easy!

Can this please be fixed?

## update

I have ran into [another audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3310034) which I decided to edit - the question was tagged VBA and I thought it had nothing to do with VBA so I selected Edit which was the correct action.

Now, once the first audit was clearly one to close - nothing to do with VBA and really easy to know that it actually was an audit - the second one was a very good audit.

I am just thinking now if this is a proper bug or just a matter of malfunction in the system. I think the first one may have been made an audit for the wrong reason.

Let's turn this into a discussion as I can't clearly work the system out.

Comment: if you notice the question is mistagged for your filter, you are paying attention. That's what the audits are for.

Comment: @JanDvorak but if the question is mistagged for my filter I am still required to take the proper action which may not always be `closing`. I can skip - but then what is the point of having the filter in first place?

Comment: I also just got [an audit that had nothing to do with my tag filter](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4063600). I was so confused by the tags that I went to the real question and almost left a snarky comment about learning to read the tag wiki excerpts when tagging a question. That could have even embarrassing :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For technical reasons we aren't querying for audits with filters enabled, we just fake the audit post, so that it looks like it matches your filters. While reviewing the faked posts appears like it matches your filters:

[image: audit]

Unfortunately you don't see the faked post in the audit result because we don't save filter setting snapshots with the review results:

[image: result]

Otherwise this completely serves the purpose of testing whether or not you're paying attention to what you click while reviewing

Comment: Heh, you finally managed to audit me by doing this, after 250+ votes with no audits. They're pretty obvious when I filter on R and see questions on c#. However, it actually worked on me (as I failed the first one), so good on ya.

Comment: Can you expand on the technical reason? Is it performance or something else?

Comment: What about people that filter only duplicates?  Based on [this recent question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227172/i-always-know-when-i-get-review-audits), it seems that you aren't even making an attempt to match the filters?

Comment: @psubsee2003 will check it out, tnx for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @m0sa if it is a legit bug, could you please reopen it.  Right now, it is closed as a dup of this one.

Comment: I have just been reviewing the close queue for just [C#] but I was given http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7046931?filter-tags=c%23 . This question is only tagged with [Ruby]. This meta Q&A suggests I should also be seeing an faked [C#] tag for this audit.