# Don't fail my audit just because I clicked Close

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

So today I failed my first review audit. I had gone to [close questions specifically filtered with sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/549832?filter-tags=sql-server-2008&burn=1) and, when [this question popped up](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4200279), I clicked <kbd>Close</kbd> simply to see why others might have voted to close (which I can do just fine, without actually voting to close, when it's not an audit).

I don't think I should fail the button the moment I click <kbd>Close</kbd>. Just like on a normal question outside of a queue scenario, I don't commit my vote to close the moment I click the Close link on a question. Especially since the VtC reasons have changed so many times in my time here, I sometimes review the VtC reasons before really deciding if I think that one of the close reason fits. (Also, sometimes, to see what might have gotten it on the queue in the first place, particularly when I wonder whether it should be closed at all - did I miss something? did the close voter(s)?)

I don't really think it's fair to tell me I'm not paying attention when I click <kbd>Close</kbd> - I really didn't expect *that* action to be *the* audit. Now I know that this is a trick, but think of all the people reviewing for the first time and ultimately getting screwed over by these shenanigans.

Also, and just as an aside, I don't think automatically generated audits should include questions outside of what I've filtered. That's been [rejected as by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204639/audits-bug-in-the-filtered-review-queue) before, but I have to be honest, I don't also look at the tags when I'm checking if I agree with others' reasoning for voting to close.

I am not reviewing for reputation or badges obviously, just trying to help out with the close queue. Guess I won't be doing that anymore.

Comment: I find with those audits my first thought is "why the hell is this tagged SQL Server?". Second thought. Oh it must be an audit.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, I guess I have a happier trigger finger - I didn't even look at the tag, I just assumed that the question was tagged to match my filter. But on reviewing the actual question I was curious why it ended up on the close vote queue - did I miss something about the question, or did the close voter(s)? I think this is a pretty crappy way to fail an audit - smells like entrapment to me. Clicking "Close" isn't voting to close, it's supposed to just pop up the VtC dialog.

Comment: Yes the accepted answer in the dupe seems more like how it *ought* to behave.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yup completely agreed, that was happened first time with me also because I was not aware about the system