# When reviewing queue tagged by ``[tag]`` test question should be honestly related to the tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, review-audits

When I'm reviewing close queue by tag (`python`) but thats irrevelant sometimes I get questions that are not related to python at all, but are tagged python. Obvious solution would be to edit them to remove invalid tag.

But it turns out that this was just a test. And I was supposed to approve that question, because (otherwise being apparently tagged wrongly) question is OK. Moreover invalid tag is displayed only on revieved queue, and not on the question itself.

I guess that only questions properly tagged should be chosen as tests, as this is confusing as hell.

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5001242) tagged python on queue: [image]

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043577/partial-aggregate-initialization-and-non-static-data-member-initializer) on the site:

[image]

Comment: Was the question initially tagged as python and removed afterwards? Maybe that's the bug.

Comment: @Rob Checked that! and no. this was not tagged as python. I have also included question link.

Answer (score 3):

When you select `edit`, that's a *valid* action, and you've passed the audit. The point of audits is to check if you were paying attention. Congrats, you were!

Actually filtering audits by tags is too expensive, so a random audit is chosen, and the tag added to help make it quasi-believable.

Remember, audits are intended to prevent robo-reviewing. They don't have to be perfect - just good enough to make sure you were paying attention and took an appropriate action.

Comment: Actually I checked that something is wrong with tags, and assumed it was test so I clicked Accept ;) 

Second problem is that this is just confusing.

Comment: vague hand-waving and "technical reasons" from a dev: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204645/248072

Comment: OK. So this is a duplicate or something.

Comment: I had considered that before answering, but I think the approach of your question is a little different

Comment: Then let's hope someone notices that and fixes it.

Comment: well the purpose of audits is just to ensure you're giving the review your attention, not that they're ironclad traps of perfection