# Review Queue Filter Doesn't Seem to be Filtering Good

Tags: support, review, filtering, tag-filters

So I was [trying to do my duty and review some stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut), but I'm not exactly the most knowledgeable in the realm of programming. So I figured I would filter the review list to get questions I could answer. So I tried to review javascript only and all seemed to be well:

> [image: javascript filter]

Only [the question doesn't seem to be javascript at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064519/why-doesnt-explicit-bool-conversion-happen-in-contextual-conversion), I think to myself as I read it, and then come to the tags at the bottom:

> [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) [operator-overloading](/questions/tagged/operator-overloading)

Yeah, definitely not javascript. What's going on here?

> [image: failed filter]

Comment: @Lower, I skipped it since I have absolutely no bloody idea what I was supposed to do with it as I am not savvy in the ways of c++.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204269/223030

Comment: So not cool. Trying to do good, get tripped up on my third review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It definitely looks like an audit. [Why doesn't explicit bool() conversion happen in contextual conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064519/why-doesnt-explicit-bool-conversion-happen-in-contextual-conversion) It has +11 score.

Some people have said you can sometimes tell if it's an audit if the tag doesn't match your filter.

Comment: Sweet lord almighty, you are right. I feel like a dunce.

Comment: It's a pretty big tell too; I think I remember a feature-request suggesting we take that out so that those audits aren't so obvious.