# "Acceptable" Honeypot Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-audits

Currently, the "Suggested Edits" audits only are edits that should be rejected a vandalism. Why aren't there any that edit code, but are valid edits?

Look at [Suggested Edit #1978835](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1978835). If the reviewer were to look at the edit comment, it would be apparent that the edit was valid. As such, I accepted the edit, but it was subsequently rejected (very quickly) by three other people.

Being a valid edit, I copied the markdown for the edit and pasted it over the question's contents. However, this raised some questions about rejecting edits.

- Should this edit have been rejected?
- What should we do if a valid edit is rejected?
- Can we have some valid edits used as audits?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that edit was not actually valid. Edits which change code are very, very rarely acceptable. Code is the OP's job. Also, if you look at the markdown, the editor removed an enormous block of code. Again, that's the OP's job.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi the comment said that the comments made the removed code irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not reading from the comments of this question.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi the edit comment is what I'm referring to...

Comment: If the edit comment says that the edit rationale is based off question's comments, and the edit doesn't make sense on its own, check the question's comments.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi ok, well, disregard the edit for now, what about the honeypot?

Comment: To address that point, there actually are valid edits in audits. They're just not particularly frequent.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I have yet to experience one — and I've reviewed _>1000_ edits!